# Setting List<E> files in location for later use

Tags: java, android, list

I'm working on some kind of a game. There are default values that don't change and are stored in a list. My question is, is there a way to make a list once and add it to the app files so if I need the list all I need to do is `List<E>` new = mylist? or something along those lines? I could work with arrays if needed but preferably lists.

Comment: Cash it like  resource files, How about dah ?

Comment: Yes, Pretty much that. Sorry but, couldn't find anything online.

Comment: Use Resource Bundle https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html

Comment: or use enums or contant file,

Comment: Problem with enums(Pretty new correct me if I'm wrong) is that I have to set all the enums at the start. With a huge list of 250 classes that contain several more classes in them, wouldn't it be too heavy for the phone to handle?

Comment: so you want static fields right ? like String name="John Doe" , constants ? like this, If I am right

Comment: Yeah. A static list.